# Mathematical Foundations of Quantum Mechanics

Tags: reference-request, quantum-mechanics

As the title says, I am interested in a textbook/reference that deals exclusively with the mathematical foundations of quantum mechanics, without (or, with minimal) physics involved.

As an example on what I am looking for, is a text in the flavor of (but more extensive than) the 2nd chapter of Nielsen & Chuang's "Quantum Computation and Quantum Information" which contains math formalism without any physics stuff involved.

Thanks

Comment: Quantum mechanics and Quantum Computation  are two completely different areas.

Comment: @zkutch Did I imply somewhere that they are similar areas?

Comment: In title is one, in text another.

Comment: You can see some texbooks here: https://moretti.maths.unitn.it/recent.html

Comment: @zkutch I am sorry but I do not understand what you mean. In the text I refer to Chapter 2 of the book which is exclusively about the math formalisms of quantum _mechanics_.

Comment: The first book that comes to mind is von Neumann's [Mathematical Foundations of Quantum Mechanics](https://books.google.com/books/about/Mathematical_Foundations_of_Quantum_Mech.html?id=JLyCo3RO4qUC) (literally sharing a title with this question).

Comment: If you want "extensive", then I doubt if anything could beat Reed and Simons's massive 4-volume blockbuster [*Methods of Modern Mathematical Physics*](https://www.elsevier.com/books-and-journals/book-series/methods-of-modern-mathematical-physics).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure how to do your "flavor" comparison for you, but you seem to be asking for "more but rigorous". In your shoes, I'd start from a modern bare minimum text such as

- Brian Hall's *Quantum Theory for Mathematicians (Graduate Texts in Mathematics, 267)* ;  (Springer; 2013  edition    ISBN-13: 978-1461471158)

It is in today's language, covers the bases and the bare rigorous minimum you appear interested in,  and eschews the alternate universe that absorbs mathematical physicists' and functional analysts'  attention.

Comment: Ευχαριστώ! I was not aware of this text and it seems to contain much of what I am interested in.